# define an indicator when number of duplicate rows -1 is equal one of the column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some duplicate rows whose are the same in some columns, I want to define indicator if the number of duplicate rows -1 are equal the number of one of the column .

example

```
        SAMPN       PERNO       ARR_HR      HHMEM
          1           1           2           1
          1           2           2           1
          2           1           3           2 
          2           3           3           2
          3           1           4           2
          3           2           4           2
          3           3           4           2
```

rows are duplicate if they are the same in first ,second and third columns. I want the indicator to be 1   if number of duplicate rows -1 is equal HHMEM  .
for example 2 first rows are duplicate so `2-1=1=HHMEM` so indicator is 1.

out put

```
       SAMPN       PERNO       ARR_HR      HHMEM        indicator
          1           1           2           1              1
          1           2           2           1              1
          2           1           3           2              0
          2           3           3           2              0
          3           1           4           2              1
          3           2           4           2              1
          3           3           4           2              1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'SAMPN' and other grouping variables (from OP's comments) create the 'indicator' by coercing the logical vector (`(n()- 1) == HHMEM`) into binary with `as.integer`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      group_by(SAMPN, ARR_HR, HHMEM) %>%
      mutate(indicator = as.integer((n()-1) == HHMEM))
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   SAMPN [3]
#  SAMPN PERNO ARR_HR HHMEM indicator
#  <int> <int>  <int> <int>     <int>
#1     1     1      2     1         1
#2     1     2      2     1         1
#3     2     1      3     2         0
#4     2     3      3     2         0
#5     3     1      4     2         1
#6     3     2      4     2         1
#7     3     3      4     2         1
```

NOTE: We don't need to create any additional column and then remove it later

---

Or the same logic in `base R` with `ave`

```
df1$indicator <- +(with(df1, HHMEM == ave(HHMEM, HHMEM, SAMPN,
                 ARR_HR, FUN = length)-1))
```

Or using `duplicated` with `table`

```
i1 <- table(cumsum(!duplicated(df1[c(1, 3, 4)])))
as.integer(rep(i1, i1) - 1 ==  df1$HHMEM)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SAMPN = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), PERNO = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), ARR_HR = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), HHMEM = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: I think I should group by SAMPN and ARR_HR and HHMEM. right?

Comment: @hghg Based on the data showed, that is also a possibility

Comment: as.integer(n()) is the number of elements in a group?

Comment: @hghg Here, `n()` is the total number of elements in each group, similar to `nrow()` from base R.  Then we subtract 1 and compare with the values of the column

Answer (score 0):

We can use `add_count` to get count and compare it with `HHMEM`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 add_count(SAMPN, ARR_HR, HHMEM) %>%
 mutate(indicator = as.integer(n - 1 == HHMEM)) %>%
 select(-n)

#  SAMPN PERNO ARR_HR HHMEM indicator
#  <int> <int>  <int> <int>     <int>
#1     1     1      2     1         1
#2     1     2      2     1         1
#3     2     1      3     2         0
#4     2     3      3     2         0
#5     3     1      4     2         1
#6     3     2      4     2         1
#7     3     3      4     2         1
```